# Reduce multiple field values in CouchDB

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

For a notification system I am storing user messages in CouchDB. My document structure looks like this:

```
{
   "_id": "bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae81b609",
   "_rev": "1-9745ddb21cefe3dbc8cc1f7f7bd8d11d",
   "uid": "bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29",
   "msg": "Hi there, here is a message for you!",
   "level": "warning",
   "status": "new",
   "created": 1467180077,
   "read": null
}
```

The field *status* can have the two values `new` or `read` - I am trying to write a Map/Reduce view to return a count for a certain user with how many messages they have with the status `new` and how many with the status `read`.

The Map Function is pretty straight forward:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.uid, doc.status);
}
```

and it returns something like this:

```
| key                                | value
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
| bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29   | "read"
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
| bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29   | "read"
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
| bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29   | "read"
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
| bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29   | "new"
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
| bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29   | "new"
```

I am trying now to figure out how to write a reduce function that would produce this:

```
| key                                | value
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
| bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29   | ["read":3, "new":2]
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
```

If I use this reduce function

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
    return  values;
}
```

I get:

```
| key                                | value
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
| bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29   | ["read","read","read","new","new"]
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
```

I tried to use `return count(values)` but it returns `null`.

It seems I can't wrap my head around, how to approach this. Anyone who could put me on the right track here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to emit the `uid` and `status` as your key, then you will get the counts as your reduced value.

First, we'll start with the map function:

```
function (doc) {
  emit([ doc.uid, doc.status ]);
}
```

Notice we're emitting a key only, and we're not bothering with a value. (it turns out we don't need it in this case)

Then, use the following [built-in reduce function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#builtin-reduce-functions)

```
_count
```

Your view output will have keys like: (remember, we don't care about value)

- `[ "bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29", "read" ]`
- `[ "bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29", "read" ]`
- `[ "bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29", "read" ]`
- `[ "bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29", "new" ]`
- `[ "bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29", "new" ]`

When you query the view, make sure to include `group=true` (the `reduce=true` is implied)

You'll notice that your view has the following key/value pairs now:

- `[ "bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29", "read" ]: 3`
- `[ "bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29", "new" ]: 2`

If your database has more documents in it, you'll see all the other user ids as well. To filter down to the user you care about, simply use:

- `startkey=["bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29"]`
- `endkey=["bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29",{}]`

These arrays look kinda weird, I'm sure, but those just ensure that any values for the "status" will be matched. (check out the documentation on [Views Collation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/collation.html#examples) for more information)

This approach will scale up rather nicely, allowing any other `status` values to work without any code changes.

Comment: That was exactly my first approach, but as a result I get something like this:
`[ "bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29", 5 ]` - What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure to add `group=true` to your query. By default, it will reduce the entire resultset.

Comment: here is url I am querying: `/notification/_design/msg/_view/count2?group=true&startkey="bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29"&endkey="bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29"` but I get back:
`{"key":"bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29","value":5}` -  any ideas, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Take look at my example again, they need to be those JSON arrays. (ie: `startkey=["bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29"]&endkey=["bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29",{}]`)

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much, this actually works and I learned something new today :)

Comment: No problem, CouchDB's map/reduce model can be a little tricky to wrap your head around, but it's way more powerful/flexible than many realize at first glance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this, but I am not sure if it is the right approach:

The reduce function:

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
    var result = new Object;
    result.read = 0;
    result.new = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i){
        if(values[i] == 'new'){
                result.new++;
        }
            if(values[i] == 'read'){
                result.read++;
        }
    };
    return result;
}
```

will produce this result:

```
| key                                | value
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
| bc325c2f6a99194ecab6e7bbae80eb29   | {read: 2, new: 1}
+------------------------------------+------------------------------
```

Comment: Just a heads-up that this will break when the `rereduce` case becomes true. (once you start to get heavier real-world usage)